# Paul Walker body doubles in Fast & Furious 7

Tags: casting, effects, fast-and-furious-franchise, furious-7

I had just recently watched Fast & Furious 7.  I am aware that Paul Walker's two brothers stood in as a body double for his character in order to finish filming some scenes.

I am also aware that they used CGI with his brothers as well.

My question is, does anyone know which scenes in the movie that his brothers were used in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Wiki on [Fast 7 - Filming](http://fastandfurious.wikia.com/wiki/Furious_7#Filming) mentions (and shows an image of) one particular example at the end of the film.

[image: Paul Walker CGI Face]

Paul's face is CGI'd over whoever's torso they used for that scene. It is vague on the matter of other scenes though, simply mentioning that they also used it in scenes newly written to support the concept of Brian 'retiring' from Dom's group<sup>1</sup>.

That particular image would have been as Brian pulled up beside Dom, chiding him for leaving the beach without saying goodbye.

1. I expect those scenes were when Dom/Mia/Brian are in conversation as to him 'missing the bullets' and possibly the mini-van scene at the school (showing his awkwardness with family life).

Comment: [Hollywood Reporter](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/behind-screen/furious-7-how-peter-jacksons-784157) revealed that Peter Jackson's Weta Digital company did the CGI replacement.

Answer (score -3):

the scene which a bomb explode near Dom's house and its wave throw brian to car's window , its pretty obvious thats not him actually .

Comment: any citation or concreate theory to backup your answer?

Comment: *"..throw brian to car's window.."*  I'm thinking Dom & Brian looked like 'stunt men' and Mia looked like a 'stunt woman' in that scene..

Comment: @AndrewThompson agreed.  However, I am sure that Paul Walker did not do all of his own stunts...(especially this one) even if he was still alive when that scene was filmed.  Looks like all of their stunt doubles probably did that scene.  I just want to know the scenes that his brother's "stood in" or CGI was used with them doubling for Paul Walker.

Comment: @steelerfan  Yep.  We're on the same page.  This answer is irrelevant to that question.